# How to find the same records and do an action for each rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to solve a huge problem.

**Context** : e-commerce subject. I have multiple Products, that customers can add into a Cart. Each Product can have multiple DeliveryMods (Exemple: express, low cost).

I want to find **each time where the DeliveryMods of the Products are different**, and create a LogisticalCart for each. The result would look like :

- Product1 : DeliveryMods = a & b
- Product2 : DeliveryMods = b
- Product3 : DeliveryMods = a & b

*Product1 and Product3 have the same DeliveryMods, but not Product2.*

2 combinations of DeliveryMods, so 2 LogisticalCart to create.
**Result : 2 LogisticalCart created.**

I've tried a lot of things, and I don't know how to do with it. Any solutions please ?

*Important :*

Product & DeliveryMod relation is a "has_and_belongs_to_many" with join table.

*Code try (don't work) :*

```
  @products = current_cart.products
    @products.each do |product|
      @delivery_mods = Array.new
      @delivery_mods << product.delivery_mods
      if @delivery_mods.all? { |item| item.eql?item}
        @logistical_cart = LogisticalCart.new
        @logistical_cart.save
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Product1 and Product3 have the same DeliveryMods

Does it mean, that Product1 and Product3 have delivery_mods with the same ids? Do you need to pass anything else, besides delivery_mod_ids? Please, clarify all the details at once :)

```
@products = current_cart.products
mod_ids_uniq = @products.map(&:delivery_mod_ids).uniq
mod_ids_uniq.each do |ids|
  LogisticalCart.create(delivery_mod_ids: ids)
end
```

Comment: Hi @Vasilisa, it's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. A precision please, how can I pass an object in this hash at **each .time** ? I want to add things like `@new_cart.delivery_mods = products.delivery_mods` with the `LogisticalCart.create`

Comment: @Gdebrick, if my answer works for you, please, accept it as correct